# Azure Function throwing error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Specialized

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, mongodb-.net-driver, .net-7.0

I have the following azure function that works locally and remotely (in Azure), but when I try to use a System.Web.HttpUtility class to parse a filter, I get the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
> GetPetitions. MasterProbaterApi: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Collections.Specialized, Version=7.0.0.0,.... The system
> cannot find the file specified.

This line is the culprit: "System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection xxx = ..." (see below). With this line commented out, the function works fine.

```
using MasterProbaterRepo;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespaceApi
{
    public static class MyPoco
    {
        private static IMyPocoService _repo = new MongoRepo(); 
        
        [FunctionName("GetMyPoco")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> GetMyPocoAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "myPoco")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            //System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection xxx = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("?param1=aaa&param2=bbb"); //causes runtime error
            var myPoco = await _repo.GetMyPocoAsync();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myPoco);
            return new OkObjectResult(json);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: GetPetitions. MasterProbaterApi: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Specialized, Version=7.0.0.0,.... The system cannot find the file specified.

This indicates that `System.Collections.Specialized` dependency is missing in the project or the version of the package is not compatible with the project.

If you are trying to include the assembly 'System.Collections.Specialized' version=7.0.0 in your project, it is still not released yet.
As mentioned in the [doc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Specialized), The latest version of the package `System.Collections.Specialized` is 4.3.0.

[image]

[image]

***So, try to reduce the version of `System.Collections.Specialized` in your project to 4.3.0 or below versions.***

---

I have created a Http Trigger Azure function and used the package `System.Collections.Specialized`:

***Code Snippet:***

```cs
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(req.QueryString.Value);
            string param1 = query["param1"];
            string param2 = query["param2"];
            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2)
                ? "Please pass param1 and param2 in the query string"
                : $"Hello, {param1} and {param2}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
            retur
```

***Dependencies:***

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Collections.Specialized" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

***Output:***
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I was able to create a new .net 7 isolated project that worked right away. The new project had 3 ".Azure.Function.Worker" dependencies that were not in my "upgraded to .net 7" project. The .net 6 in process project uses an entirely different set of dependencies and allows for typed IActionResult tasks vs the newer/inferior HttpResponseData ones.

Thanks for your efforts! It led me to find the issue.